# Convert DateTime Type to ISODate MongoDB with json_serializable flutter package

Tags: mongodb, flutter, flutter-dependencies, json-serializable

everyone i am using MongoDB as my backend , i don't have any clues how can i convert **DateTime type** to **ISODate MongoDB** , i try to look through document and searching , i can't find anything about it , do you have any idea about this ? thank in advance

Comment: @JahidulIslam yeah , here what i'm doing right now i want to insert date type from flutter to mongoDB and then get it back as type datetime , but i don't know how can i convert dateTime type on json serialzable package , can you show me how can i do it ?

Answer (score 2):

you can convert dart DateTime to ISO8601Date format with code like this :

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String isoDate = now.toIso8601String();
```

Comment: no , it isn't what i want , i just want to know how can i convert DateTime type to ISODate type on mongoDB by json_serializable package

Comment: you can, do not use the json_serializable package and make your JSON as a string then encrypts to JSON.

Comment: i can not do that , my whole project completely using json_serializable package , any  idea or choice ?

Comment: nvm, thank you , it solved

Comment: @HengYouSour how did you solve the problem?

Comment: @saibot here what i did
`@JsonKey(
      fromJson: CoreModelConverter.convertDateTimeForModel,
      toJson: CoreModelConverter.convertDateTimeForModel,
      disallowNullValue: true)
  final DateTime? createdAt;
`


`class CoreModelConverter {
  static DateTime? convertDateTimeForModel(DateTime? dateTime) => dateTime;
}`